# Will the track length increase to keep the light velocity constant?

Tags: spacetime, speed-of-light, relativity

Assuming light travels at 3 km/sec(for calculation purposes), what happens when a 1 km long train moving at 2 km/sec along a straight track switches on its headlight at 30 km distance from a wall.So now,since the relative velocity of light becomes (3+2) km/sec, Will the track length increase to keep the light velocity constant?

Assume we can see when the light hits the wall.
So If the train is stationary, we will see the light hitting the wall after 10 secods.But what happens when the train moves and its velocity gets added to the speed of light? If the speed of light was constant,we should still see the light hitting the wall after 10 seconds.How is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! could you explain why you think the distance might increase? it doesn't obviously come across from your question

Comment: Do you think that the speed of light gets faster if the source is moving in a real world scenario?

Answer (score 2):

The mistake in your question is in the second sentence, where you say that the relative velocity of light is 3+2 km/s. The whole point about relativity is that the velocity of light is the same relative to everyone. So if it is 3km/s relative to the train it is 3km/s relative to someone on the ground too, even though the train is traveling at 2km/s relative to them.

If you start with that principle, then work through your example again, you will find that the consequence is that the train driver and the person on the ground will disagree about how far the light has travelled between leaving the train and hitting the wall, and they will disagree about how long it took.

To deal with the points raised in your comments below, consider the following scenario. You are sitting in a train carriage travelling at 1m/s. I am on the platform. As you pass me, you roll a ball at 2m/s down the carriage in your direction of travel.

After a second has passed on your watch, you think the ball has travelled 2m down the carriage.
After a second has passed on my watch, I think the ball has moved 3m (2m down the carriage, plus the carriage has moved by 1m). From my perspective the speed of the ball is 3m/s.

So in everyday experience, you and I agree on the time that has elapsed, but we disagree about how far the ball has rolled and what its speed is. Note that while we disagree, neither of us is wrong- we are simply measuring the physical events in two different reference frames.

Now imagine the exact same scenario with one key difference, namely that the laws of physics say that the speed of the ball is 2m/s for all observers, regardless of their reference frame. For you in the carriage the mathematics works out the same- after a second on your watch the ball has rolled 2m, so its speed is 2m/s according to the law. For me, however, the ball has rolled 3m, so the only way in which its speed can be 2m/s for me is if my watch says that 1.5s has elapsed. So in order for us both to agree on a common speed, we have to disagree about how much time has elapsed. Matters get more complicated because you think you have only travelled a metre along the track by the time the ball has rolled 2m down the carriage, because only a second has passed. However, I think that you have moved 1.5m along the track, because more time has passed, so we disagree about distances too.

As with the original case, neither of us is wrong- we are simply making measurements in different reference frames.

Comment: They are both right, because they are measuring from their own perspective, and the two disagree.

Comment: Imagine you and I are standing 50m apart. From your perspective I look shorter than I would if I stood next to you. From my perspective the effect is reversed- you look shorter.

Comment: Hi Tintop. That's fine. I'll try to write another answer later when I get time. You'll get the hang of it. Everyone puzzles over relativity at first.

Comment: Thanks Marco for the detailed explanation. However it kind of still leaves me in confusion. Replacing the ball with light and train scenario, after 1 sec light has travelled 3 km for me, and for u it has travelled 3 + 2 = 5 km. So inorder for constant light speed, your watch should show 5/3 = 1.66 sec when my watch shows 1 sec. Now imagine that we both use a common watch on the platform instead of seperate watches and it stops after light travelled 3 km for me? What will be its time?

Comment: You can't use a common watch- that's the point. You can only both get the same speed for the ball if you use different watches. That's what relativity says- there isn't a standard time for everyone.

Comment: Mhh..okay. So you are saying the mechanical watches adjust themselves inorder to keep the light speed constant.(I know this sounds foolish). I read somewhere that they actually conducted an experiment where they placed an atomic clock in a plane and after the plane finished its journey, the clock showed a small difference when compared to a fixed stationary clock.I wonder how that happened!

Comment: @TinTop. It's nothing to do with mechanical watches- all watches would behave in the same way. Time itself is different for you in the moving train and me on the platform. That's the hardest thing about relativity- you have to accept the idea that there is no standard time.

Comment: Yeah..maybe thats what i should do.Time itself is a puzzle to me, sometimes.Thanks for the time and effort you put into this. Is the experiment with plane true?Is that possible?